# Where to put AnimatePresence in NextJs 13.4

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, framer-motion, app-router

I am using NextJS 13.4 (App Router) and I want to use Framer Motion for my animations. In earlier versions of Next you could wrap the entire app with `<AnimatePresence>` in the App component like this:

```
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import { AppProps, useRouter } from 'next/app'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const pageKey = router.asPath

    return (
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
            <Component key={pageKey} {...pageProps} />
        </AnimatePresence>
    )
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same result with NextJs' App router like this, but it doesn't work:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children}: { children: React.ReactNode}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,1,0"
        />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <AnimatePresence>
          {children}
        </AnimatePresence>

        <div className="container__small">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

How do I wrap my entire component with Framer Motion AnimatePresence?

Comment: What do your page.js components look like? "AnimatePresence works by detecting when *direct children* are removed from the React tree... Direct children *must each have a unique key prop* so AnimatePresence can track their presence in the tree." Do the pages have a unique key prop on the outer most tag?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but doesn't work as well. I read that it may be a problem with Nextjs 13.4.